# Is there any option for sharing keychain data across multiple apps with different appbundles/appId's in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, keychain, android-keystore

I am developing two mobile applications using flutter targeting both android and ios with different appId's and I want to share keychain's data among these applications. Is there any such way to approach this. I have started trying intent approach for android since one week and nothing turned successful. Would be great to have any help!

Comment: Hey, what are you trying to achieve by sharing the keychain data?

Comment: I am trying to share authentication details from one app to other so that if one app gets installed and authenticated with details provided by user. The other when installed and started it will directly fetch these details from first installed app.